# Is there a way to generate source code with Jakarta instead Javax using swagger-codegen

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-codegen, jakarta-migration

I need to generate spring controller source code using swagger codegen gradle plugin with Jakarta packages but I could not see an option in config to do so

I have tried to use below options to generate swagger code:

```
additionalProperties = [
                "errorOnUnknownEnum": true,
                "dateLibrary": "java8",
                "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
                "modelPackage": "com.delphix.api.gw.model${version}",
                "apiPackage": "com.delphix.api.gw.api${version}",
                "interfaceOnly": true,
                "packageName": "api",
                "useTags": true,
                "useJakartaEe" : true,
                "useSpringBoot3" : true,
                "generateSupportingFiles" : false,
                "java11" : true,
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Raster R mentioned, setting `<jakarta>true</jakarta>` in configOptions of the plugin solves the issue. See [this PR](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/pull/1091/files#diff-d9ddc8e3eb294d8531b4c7853b759d1600c522a29513cc0ec6bd6541cf333770R82) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced with the same issue but `hideGenerationTimestamp` did the trick.

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "org.hidetake.swagger.generator" version "2.19.2"
}

implementation "io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations"
swaggerCodegen "io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli"
```

Plugin:

```
additionalProperties = [
    modelPackage            : "<my-package>.models",
    apiPackage              : "<my-package>",
    dateLibrary             : 'java8',
    interfacesOnly          : 'true',
    hideGenerationTimestamp : 'true'
]
```

Comment: I too had the same issue. I suppose it might get solved by migrating to openapi generator as suggested by @jeet427. I was able to make the codegenerator spewout jakarta code by using configOption of <jakarta>true</jakarta>  But springfox in the generated code then caused some compatibility issues. springfox seems to be still on only javax.  I didnt need springfox so removed it using maven-antrun-plugin. I would suggest try what jeet427 said. If needed try what I said as a fallback. I do see that you are using gradle which is quite different from maven that i based my experience on.